# Kentor Auth - Configure Idp with metadata stored in a database

Tags: asp.net, owin, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

We need to configure the IdentityProvider from metadata stored in a database. It would seem though that the only way to specify the metadata to IdentityProvider is through metadataLocation property which supports a URL or file path.

Is there anyway, which I've missed, to pass a stream object that holds the metadata to the IdentityProvider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way using the standard code. The Load method that takes a stream is marked as `internal`, see here:
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices/Metadata/MetadataLoader.cs

You could:

1. Write your database value to a temporary location and give this file path to load
2. Write an api route that serves up the metadata for a given Idp as a url
3. Make an open source contribution to add support for this
4. Don't use `MetadataLocation` but instead construct the `IdentityProvider` object and separately set signing key, entity id, binding etc.
5. etc.

Comment: Went with your option 2 although calling it in the Startup class caused the call WebClient OpenRead to block and timeout.